# R: groupedData() - how to fix this published code example

Tags: r

I am hoping someone can fix this published code, so I can work through the example. Someone who know about the groupedData() function, and maybe about hierarchical linear modeling.

Source: http://davidakenny.net/papers/k&h/MLM_R.pdf
Dataset: http://davidakenny.net/papers/k&h/nimh.csv

Code:  ( groupedData(...) -> error )

```
> install.packages(“nlme”)
> library(nlme)
> nimh <-read.csv("nimh.csv")
> nimh <- read.csv("nimh.csv")
> nimh2 <- groupedData(y ~ tx | therapist, data=nimh, outer= ~tx)
Error in eval(aux[[2]], object) : object 'tx' not found
```

The next line code is: (but uses nimh2 above, which was not assigned)

```
mod1 <- lme(y ~ 1, data=nimh2, random = ~ 1|therapist, na.action="na.omit")
```

Here is the format fo the dataset:

```
> head(nimh)
  X patid p_gender ypre  y therapist t_gender  bdi_gain   t
1 1  1329        1   26  1       101        1 -7.692513 IPT
2 2  1349        2   31  4       101        1 -6.216597 IPT
3 3  1428        2   24 NA       101        1        NA IPT
4 4  1502        2   25  4       101        1 -4.387696 IPT
5 5  1520        2   24  4       101        1 -4.082879 IPT
6 6  1342        1   19  2       102        1 -4.558795 IPT
```

The author says the reason for using 'tx' is:

> When using the lme()and gls()functions it can be helpful to first
> convert the data frame to a “grouped data” object.  This is
> accomplished with the groupedData()function, with arguments specifying
> a model formula (including the “|” operator to identify the main
> grouping variable), the data frame, and (optionally) any additional
> nesting variables (here, tx is an “outer” factor, as therapists are
> nested within treatments).
>
> The data in nimh2are identical to those in nimh.  The basic formula is
> stored along with the data in nimh2, which can improve default
> behavior of graphical and statistical functions designed to work with
> nested data.  Although this step is unnecessary for the main analyses
> shown here, it simplifies some operations, especially graphical
> analyses of multilevel data, and so it is good practice.

---

I have already searched Google to see if someone has posted a correction somewhere.

Comment: `tx` is not present in the data. That is why you got error!

Comment: @Duck  I know that.  I'm hoping someone someone knows whats missing from the context.  Without that first part working, the entire rest of the tutorial is useless to me.  And added the next paragraph of the quote as it provides more context as to why the author is using tx.